# Memory Profiling in the iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, memory-management

Can any one guide me in clearing the memory leaks in the iphone code.
in xcode editor it does not shows any issues,
so i hav uploaded my app to the AppleStore.
they rejected my app.
so kindly help me what is my issue?
how to rectify it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Leaks.
Use performance tool to help you find memory leaks.

Comment: ya thanks,but there is no proper documentation.can u pl guide me

Comment: It will save you time that you read some documents on apple official site, or run the performance tool directly. Explain how to use needs too much time. And I am not good at English.